# cmd command to go to a sub directory of where the batch file was opened

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

So that title was confusing.  Let me tell you my needs:
I'm wanting to open a batch file that is located in `c:\documents\test\`

in this batch file i'm wanting to collect the names in c:\documents\test\data and convert it to a text file.

Now the easy way to do this would be:

```
CD c:\documents\test\data
dir/b/o:n > names.txt
```

but my issue is that i want to move the folder "\test" around and always be able to call on the names in the "\data" file.

Therefore this is what i really need:

```
CD [variable that says current location] + "\data"
```

but i dont know how to do this.  Please explain your answers thanks.

Comment: Are you saying you want to be able to know the location of the file no matter where you move it?

Comment: Yes but see below, my issue is when i open the batch from vba, it opens it prompting in a different directory than where it was saved.

Answer (score 3):

`%~dp0` is the location of the batch file (Run `FOR /?` for more info)

Answer (score 1):

the . character represents the current working directory... does

```
cd .\data
```

do what you need?

edit:

So I see no one really answered your issue. Based on your current edit you would want to define a windows environment variable that held the path to wherever your data folder is, and when you move the folder part of that process would need to update the environment variable so your batch script can find it appropriately.

so if you moved your data folder to C:\archive\test\data you would need some process to call the command line with

```
SET BATCH_ARCHIVE_PATH="C:\archive\test"
```

then in your batch script you would do something like:

```
CD "%BATCH_ARCHIVE_PATH%\data"
dir/b/o:n > names.txt
```

Comment: Ok, apparently this wasn't the issue. my issue is that when i open my batch file in vba, the command prompt opens up for example c:\windows and so my batch commands wont work.  however when i go to the batch file itself and double click it, it works.  This is cause when i open this batch file, the command window defaults to where the batch file is saved at.  How do i get around this when opening batch files in VBA?

Comment: @Jason its been a while but just saw your edit, I updated my answer with a possible solution